# PaddleOCR slim models don't work on Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I'm trying to host PaddleOCR model on AWS SageMaker endpoint. I've tried with 2 configurations:

I'm trying 2 different configurations:

1. Normal (large):

   - det: [en_PP-OCRv3_det](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar)
   - rec: [en_PP-OCRv3_rec](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_rec_infer.tar)
   - cls: [ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/dygraph_v2.0/ch/ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_infer.tar)
2. Slim:

   - det: [en_PP-OCRv3_det_slim](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_slim_infer.tar)
   - rec: [en_PP-OCRv3_rec_slim](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_rec_slim_infer.tar)
   - cls: [ch_ppocr_mobile_slim_v2.0_cls](https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/dygraph_v2.0/ch/ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_slim_infer.tar)

Normal (1) model is successfully deployed. Inference time is ~1.5s.
Slim (2) model is successfully deployed, but when it's invoked, the inference runs for a very long and fails after 60s.

System configuration:

- `ml.t2.medium` Sagemaker instance
- container `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:2.0.1-cpu-py310-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker`
- Paddle: 2.5.0
- PaddleOCR: 2.6.0.1

Why isn't Slim model able to run?

Comment: 2 comments -
1. What is the local inference time before moving to SageMaker?
2. RealTime endpoints have a timeout of 60s, if your requirement is higher check out Async Inference whose timeout is 60mins.
3. Try to use the latest DLCs here - https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md

Comment: 1. < 1s
2. My requirement is that the model finishes in <2s. Therefore I'm using the larger model, as it somehow runs faster
3. I'm already using the latest DLC (as of 07/17/2023)